# How redirect to login page if not authenticated

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am newbie in Blazor development.
I'm starting with the development of a Blazor Server App.
I would like the user to be redirected to the login page when is not logged in. Where (in what file) can I enter this check and how redirect it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401138/blazor-redirect-to-login-page-when-there-is-no-session-jwt-token

Comment: Thanks for reply. In the above question we talk about JWT token. I'm developing a server app and I don't have a JWT token. I just need to know where to put the global redirection code to the login page in case no-authentication, avoiding checking this in all component.